# Python Multiprocessing Timeout

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a program that continuously gets data from a database, then process the data and then upload it to a server via FTP. It looks like:

```
feed = connect2database()
for data in feed.changes():
    data = process(data)
    ftpUpload(data)
```

The problem here is that the ftp upload may hang forever, which will cause the program to hang. I want to implement a way to do the upload in subprocesses, set a timeout to each of them, and if any one times out, just kill it. I don't need to get any data back from the subprocesses, nor do I need to retry if the upload fails.

But I don't want to do a `.join(time)`, because the main process has to stop there to wait. I just want the main process to continuously fetch data and then fork subprocess to do the upload, it it exceeds the timeout, just kill it to avoid zombies. That's all. Can anybody suggest an architecture? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Pebble](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pebble) for that.

```
from pebble.process import concurrent

TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS = 5

feed = connect2database()
for data in feed.changes():
    data = process(data)
    concurrent(target=ftpUpload, args=(data, ), timeout=TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS)
```

Comment: The doc does not say what will happen if the "concurrent" process times out. Will it be killed automatically if it hangs? Otherwise, it'll become a zombie process, same as using the built-in multiprocessing module.

Comment: Yes. It will be killed and joined automatically.

Answer (score 1):

One good framework to use for a task like this is [Luigi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/luigi).  It's designed for data dependency, but you can easily set the timeout for each task, and you can set it so it doesn't retry failed tasks.  [Here's](http://luigi.readthedocs.org/en/stable/example_top_artists.html) the original example of usage of Luigi.

To set timeout for each task, set `worker-timeout` to the amount of time in seconds.  http://luigi.readthedocs.org/en/stable/configuration.html

To set luigi so it won't retry tasks, set disable_failures to 0.  http://luigi.readthedocs.org/en/stable/_modules/luigi/scheduler.html

It does take a good amount of work to learn how luigi works though, and documentation is sparser than I would like.  The [Luigi Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/luigi-user) is where many of the luigi questions/answers live.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I've been using Celery, I think both of them are too heavy for such simple task. It's just a small script that does a simple FTP upload. Thanks anyway.